A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade on react-native
When I try to compile my react-native app, it shows me the following error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     /home/gradle/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/734e09337e50dcd6ea1d108dc24e8565/common-ui-4.0.5/AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-27:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.
         
     /home/gradle/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/734e09337e50dcd6ea1d108dc24e8565/common-ui-4.0.5/AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-27:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.

I checked app/build.gradle, but everything looks fine.
